# XML WYSIWYG editor

Tags: gratis, linux, xml

I want a free software that can

1. Edit XML without displaying the tags (kind of WYSIWYG).
2. Run on Linux.

These would be ideal, but not necessary:

1. Open-source.
2. DocBook support.
3. CSS styling.

Comment: “Edit XML without displaying the tags” is a weird requirement, since XML tags don't have a defined meaning (it's not like, say, HTML, where you can use bold text to convey “this is inside a `<strong>” tag etc.). How would you want to view and insert tags in the document? Would you want whitespace to be rendered as is or would you want a rendering that shows the tag structure?

Comment: I was thinking of something like Adobe FrameMaker where the formatting is defined by the position in the document. I don't really care about how to insert tags as long as the possibility to do it exists. Like FrameMaker, it should remove the tag structure.

Comment: As far as I know, FrameMaker can only edit very particular kinds of XML files. You should probably restrict your question to one of these formats. Please post a sample of the XML file you want to edit. Thanks!

Comment: Similar: [*Free WYSIWYG DocBook editor*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/23020/1255)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Syntext Serna XML Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntext_Serna) had a free version but it changed to [CORENA Studio](http://www.corena.com/products/corena-studio/) which is no longer free. See [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21612/free-wysiwyg-xml-editor-for-mac-preferably-cross-platform) for details.

However you can still find older version for download over the internet. Here is a possible [download](http://www.toucharger.com/fiches/linux/serna-free/63959.htm).