# Free WYSIWYG xml editor for Mac (preferably cross-platform)

Tags: gratis, osx, xml, wysiwyg

Until now I was working with [Syntext Serna XML Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntext_Serna) on Mac which had a free version. It seems that it was renamed in [CORENA Studio](http://www.corena.com/products/corena-studio/) which is no longer free. I need a free [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) xml editor with:

- support for DocBook
- preferably to work on any operating system but a must is Mac OS X

Here is a sample screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I think it'll be helpful if you can include a screenshot of a suitable WYSIWYG editor since XML tags can be interpreted in a variety of ways. Perhaps you mean a WYSIWYG HTML editor?

Comment: Added a sample screenshot although you find plenty on the web...

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [XPontus](http://xpontus.sourceforge.net/), it's an open source XML editor. It should have support for DocBook: [Release Notes](http://sourceforge.net/p/xpontus/news/2005/12/xpontus-xml-editor-100-beta2/).

> ## Overview
>
> XPontus XML Editor is a simple XML Editor oriented towards text
> editing. It can perform validation(DTD, XML Schema, Relax NG, Batch
> XML validation), XSL transformations(HTML, XML, PDF, SVG), schema/DTD
> generation, XML/DTD/HTML/XSL code completion, code formatting and much
> more. The brand new version is now plugin based to solve some
> limitation issues.
>
> XPontus aims to become the free alternative to commercial XML IDES
> such as XMLSPy or Oxygen XML Editor, or Exchanger XML Editor without
> the Entreprise features for now. The application tries to provide you
> most of the features you would expect to see in a fully bloated XML
> IDE, in a familiar and conviviable manner.
>
> [image]

Comment: It is not a WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**XMLmind XML Editor**](https://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/). Here is how it compares to your requirements:

- **free:** yes, as in "gratis"; it is free for personal use and to work on open source projects ([see](https://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/which_license.html)), but it is not open source software itself
- **cross-platform:** yes – MacOS, Windows, Linux and anything running OpenJDK 14
- **Docbook support:** yes – try the example Docbook file from the "recently opened" section of the "File" menu, right after installation
- **WYSIWYG:** yes – choose any stylesheet-enabled view from the "View" menu