# Free WYSIWYG DocBook editor

Tags: gratis, xml, wysiwyg

[DocBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook) is a document expression format.

I am looking for a free DocBook editor in WYSIWYG mode.

Requirements:

- [What you see is what you get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)
- Supports as many DITA elements as possible
- Very reliable, never crashes
- User-friendly
- Free
- Can run at least on Windows, webapps OK
- Must be a DocBook editor, not a general-purpose XML editor

Comment: You mentioned in [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/14251/1935) that there are such editors. What are those you know?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I don't have enough experience with any to write a good answer unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML WYSIWYG editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20278/xml-wysiwyg-editor)

Comment: @BasilBourque: Not duplicate as that question asks for a general-purpose XML editor, with only optional DocBook support. DocBook, like ODT, is a very special XML format with specialized tools for it. To edit ODT you would use LibreOffice, even if in theory you could use a general-purpose XML editor (that would be incredibly cumbersome). Same here.

Comment: Why DocBook? In the past I liked formats like this (Sphinx, ...) too. But now I realized: there is no need for printed documents any more (at least in my projects). HTML is known to all people I work with. That's why we use it now for documenting.

Comment: @guetti: Printed manuals for consumer electronics (fridges, copy machines, etc)

Answer (score 8):

This could be little late but how about [XmlMind DocBook Editor Personal Edition](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/download.shtml). It is free-ware!

Note that it's not open source. *(In other words it's not licensed as a GNU style open source type of free.)*

[image]

Comment: You could at least have added a URL, although we would prefer it if you would tell us more about the app, and how it answers the OP's question

Comment: Hi Samuel! Better late than never :-) However, please add more information, and ideally a screenshot. See what is required for a good answer: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality Cheers!

Comment: ok added the link! Just thought in this day and age it is easy to be lazy. If someone wants to get to the details, they could just select and select the keyword and search in Google.

BTW: I have installed XmlMind on my machine as a backup to a paid editor OxygenXml

Comment: BTW, while this is free to use, as in free-ware, it's not free software as in free and open source software.  See their "Personal Edition License".  http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/which_license.html

Answer (score 0):

[ThotBook](http://www.nongnu.org/thotbook/faq.html) is a free editor that can edit DocBook files.

> ThotBook is (will be) a visual editor for DocBook, based on ThotLib.
>   ThotBook will allow users to visually edit DocBook documents using a
>   graphical interface and will allow them to import/export their work
>   into structured DocBook SGML/XML. ThotBook will help to produce valid
>   structured DocBook documents without having to learn the DocBook
>   syntax. ThotBook will respect document structure, as opposed to
>   "WYSIWYG" editors, which produce (mostly) unstructured documents.

Comment: Is this project alive? According to the history last commits into the [CVS repository](http://cvs.savannah.nongnu.org/viewvc/thotbook/thoteditor/) happened ~20 years ago...